# Why doesn't my window get WM_SIZE command when handling WM_KEYDOWN myself?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am unable to get WM_SIZE command if i use this method (or WM_KEYUP with same `return 0` in end):

```
case WM_KEYDOWN: {
    keys[wParam] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me WM_SIZE command when i use this:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN: {
    keys[wParam] = 1;
    break;
}
```

Could someone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Could we see the entire `switch` statement?

Comment: @Thomas, i went through the switch statement again, and surprisingly i found a statement without `break` in end, and that fixed it! This whole thing is confusing too, im not sure when should i use `break` and when `return 0` or `return 1`. When I replaced that added `break` command with `return 0`, then the bug appeared again, not sure how this all works... ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why `WM_KEYDOWN` would be expected to generate a `WM_SIZE` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the entire code, my guess is that the `return` statement is preventing the `WM_KEYDOWN` message from being passed to a default message handler, such as `DefWindowProc()`, so the window does not actually process the keystroke and take whatever action it needs to generate `WM_KEYUP` and `WM_SIZE` messages.